# library not found for -lBaiduMapApi

Tags: xcode, xcode5, cocoapods

I use cocoaPods in my current project.
Because the 'Baidu map iOS SDK' don't have a pod spec so I just create one.

The 'Baidu map iOS SDK' use a '.a' static library and some header files, I add them into my project through cocoaPods

But when I build my project, it always has an error:

```
ld: library not found for -lBaiduMapApi
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I google it then I try to set the Library Path in Xcode.

Both in my project and the target in Pods.

I am sure the path is correct, but the error still there.

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's weird......

I remove whole my project and Recreate a new one.

And config the Podfile, update .....

When I back to the Xcode, build, Success!!!

I can find another way to solve this problems